# Problems with Comparing Database Values and Text Input using MySQL and jQuery - Undefined Index and mysql_fetch_assoc() Errors

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, post

I am having an issue with comparing text input with the values I have stored in a local database.

When I type in text into the text input field with id of **#searchBar** I get this error:

**Notice: Undefined index: searchBit in C:\wamp\www\lifesearch\requires\search.php on line 6**

I have tried for a while now to fix this problem without any real success. I don't understand why it says that the index is undefined.

If anyone could offer a possible solution I would greatly appreciate it.

Here's the code:

***search.js***

```
function search(searchQuery) {
    $.post("requires/search.php", {searchBit:searchQuery}, function(data) {
        $("#searchResults").html(data);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#searchBar").focus(function() {
        if ($("#searchBar").val() == "start searching...") {
            $("#searchBar").val("");
        }
        $(this).addClass("searchBarFocus");
        $(this).removeClass("searchBarBlur");
    });
    $("#searchBar").blur(function() {
        $(this).addClass("searchBarBlur");
        $(this).removeClass("searchBarFocus");
    });
    $("#searchBar").keypress(function() {
        $("#searchResults").fadeOut(200);
        $("#searchResults").fadeIn(200);
    });
    $("#search").mouseleave(function() {
        $("#searchResults").fadeOut(200);
    });
    $("#searchBar").keyup(search(this.val()));
});
```

***searchBar.php***

```
<div id="search">
    <form action="requires/search.php">
        <input type="text" value="start searching..." id="searchBar" class="searchBarBlur" 
        autocomplete="off"/>
    </form>
    <div id="searchResults">
    </div>
</div>
```

***search.php***

```
<?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "websites";
    $searchBit = $_POST['searchBit'];
    mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
    mysql_select_db($database) or die("Failed to select table from database");
    $userSearch = mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($searchBit));
    $searchResults = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM sites WHERE name LIKE '$userSearch%'");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($searchResults)) {
        echo "<div class='searchResult'>".$row['name']."</div>";
    }
?>
```

***Thanks in advance!***

Comment: the query on line 10 returned false, not a resource, in other words it failed, debug it.

Comment: Ok, do you have any suggestions to help with debugging it because I'm really not sure what the issue is. Thanks.

Comment: if (!$searchResults) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

Comment: By changing 'sites' to sites I was able to get rid of the mysql_fetch_assoc error, but I am still getting Notice: Undefined index: searchBit in C:\wamp\www\lifesearch\requires\search.php on line 6. Any other suggestions as to how I might fix this issue?

Comment: check its set before assigning it

Comment: if(isset($_POST['searchBit']){
$searchBit = $_POST['searchBit'];
}

Comment: @Kevin Gurney, did you try this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your form input field doesn't have a name attribute which should be "searchBit". $_POST['searchBit'] is undefined because of that..

Comment: actully its created in the js ajax post *{searchBit:searchQuery}* if it wasn't set the search would fail, i asume he may of noticed that

Comment: Yea, unfortunately that didn't solve the issue. Any other suggestions?I am still getting the undefined error.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a bug or something, but I got a message in my inbox asking, "did you try this?" but I can't see it here for some reason so I'm not exactly sure what is being referred to.

Comment: @Kevin Gurney sorry i didn't notice that {searchBit:searchQuery}. Try to debug the posted data in your php script maybe vardump the content of the $_POST to check things really reach there.

Comment: Ok, so I tried a var_dump and it returned with string(0) "" and NULL which is incorrect because I typed in several letters into the input field, so does anyone know what might be causing this issue?

Comment: Does anyone have any solutions to this problem?

Comment: @Kevin Gurney, are you saying the values are not being posted to search.php?

Comment: Yes I believe that is the problem because I am still getting the error:  Undefined index: searchBit in C:\wamp\www\lifesearch\requires\search.php on line 6. Any suggestions?

Comment: either they are or they are not, only you can know.

Comment: The values from the database are being echoed, but the value of the input box is not being posted correctly.

Comment: the values form the db are dependent on the values being posted from the form are they not?

Comment: That is correct. I managed to get the values to compare correctly with my database values and now only the relevant database entries are being echoed out. However, I am now having the issue that when I mouseover the echoed search results, the event listener that sets the text value of a search result equal to the value of the input in the search bar is not working, and Google Chrome's developer tools do not detect any event listeners being attached to the echoed search results. Any suggestions as to how I might solve this? Do I have to set the event listener at a different time in my script?

Comment: I'm sorry. Thank you for all your help though. I appreciate it.